# How to make border-left above border-bottom?

Tags: css

I have a Bootstrap list-group that looks like:

[image: Bootstrap list-group screenshot]

This is my CSS:

```
$border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);

.customer-orders-filters {
  .list-group {
    box-shadow: $card-box-shadow;
    color: $text-color;
    font-weight: bold;

    .list-group-item {
      border-left: none;
      border-right: none;
      border-bottom: $border;

      &:first-child {
        border-top: none;
      }
      &:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
      &.active {
        border-left: 5px solid $blue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `border-left` bottom is not very right.
I tried to remove the `border-bottom` on the first-child, then add a `border-top` to the `nth-child(2)` but that doesn't work, the `border-top` is not present. I also tried to set a `border-style: outset` to the `border-bottom` of the `first-child` but without effect.

I would like that the `border-left` be totally above or totally under the `border-bottom`, but not half...

Do you know how could I fix it? Should I use a pseudo-element?

Comment: add your html code

Comment: This is how borders work - you get two “meeting triangles” in the corners. There is no way to avoid that - other than to not have both borders on the same element in the first place. You will need to nest two elements here, and apply one border to the outer, and the other to the inner one. (Or, use an absolutely positioned pseudo element to emulate one of the borders, instead of using a real one.)

Comment: Thank you @04FS, I think I will use a pseudo element, the code should be prettiest than with an empty element

Comment: You have an answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/8VC2c/2/

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a background and border like below:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  padding-left:5px;
  border-bottom:2px solid red;
  background:linear-gradient(blue,blue) left/5px 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or the opposite:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  padding-bottom:2px;
  border-left:5px solid blue;
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) bottom/100% 2px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

You can also do with box-shadow:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  padding-left:5px;
  border-bottom:2px solid red;
  box-shadow:5px 0 0 blue inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is being caused by Bootstrap adding "margin-bottom: -1px;" to the .list-group-item class. Overwriting that rule (and moving the border line to the bottom) seems to fix the issue. (At least in Chrome, I didn't test other browsers.)

Ex:

```
.list-group-item {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: $border !important;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  ... etc ...
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moyOGg

Note that making this change may have other consequences (the Bootstrap devs must have put that -1px margin rule in there for a reason) so you'll need to do some more testing!